# find the general term of the sequence, by means of power series

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find the term of the following sequence using power series
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a_{0}=-2 & \\ 
a_{1}=1 & \\ 
a_{n+2}=-5a_{n}+7a_{n+1} & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

For this purpose, let us consider the power series centered at $c=0$, $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$ note that

\begin{align*}
    f(x)&=a_{0}+a_{1}x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n \\
    &=a_{0}+a_{1}x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-5a_{n-2}+7a_{n-1})x^n \\
     &= -2+x+7x(f(x)-1)-5x^2f(x)
\end{align*}

From where $f(x)=-\frac{6x+2}{5x^2-7x+1}$

The idea is to express the above using partial fractions in the form

$$f(x)=-\frac{6x+2}{5x^2-7x+1}=\frac{A}{x-\alpha}+\frac{B}{x-\beta}$$

From where $\alpha$ y $\beta$ are roots of $x^2=7x-5$ so $\alpha=\frac{7+\sqrt{29}}{10}$ and $\beta=\frac{7-\sqrt{29}}{10}$.

Consider that $A(x-\beta)+B(x-\alpha)=6x+2$ so choose $x=\beta$ and $x=\alpha$ then

\begin{align*}
    f(x)&=\frac{\frac{6\alpha +2}{\alpha-\beta}}{x-\alpha}+\frac{\frac{6\beta +2}{\beta-\alpha}}{x-\beta} \\
    &=\frac{\frac{6\alpha +2}{\alpha-\beta}}{\alpha \left(1-\frac{x}{\alpha} \right)}+\frac{\frac{6\beta +2}{\beta-\alpha}}{\beta \left(1-\frac{x}{\beta} \right)} \\
     &= \frac{6\alpha +2}{\alpha-\beta}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{\alpha^n} \right)+\frac{6\beta +2}{\beta-\alpha}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{\beta^n} \right) \\
     &=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{6\alpha + 2}{\alpha^n(\alpha - \beta)} + \frac{6\beta + 2}{\beta^n(\beta - \alpha)}\right) x^n
\end{align*}

Hence the general term should be $\left(\frac{6\alpha + 2}{\alpha^n(\alpha - \beta)} + \frac{6\beta + 2}{\beta^n(\beta - \alpha)}\right)$

If we compare with [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%20a%5B0%5D%3D-2%2C%20a%5B1%5D%3D1%2C%20a%5Bn%2B2%5D%3D-5a%5Bn%5D%2B7a%5Bn%2B1%5D), we must have that the true general term is

$$a_{n}=\left(\frac{7}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{29}}{2} \right)^n\left(-1 - \frac{8\sqrt{29}}{29} \right)+\left(\frac{7}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{29}}{2} \right)^n\left(\frac{8\sqrt{29}}{29}-1 \right)$$

I have my doubts with the result, and if the roots that this selecting are the adequate ones. Any help is appreciated